Understanding how band gaps come out of electron dispersion relations
I am taking an introductory course in condensed matter physics that follows C. Kittel, Introduction to Solid State Physics, 8th edition, Wiley (2005). I feel quite happy with what I might call "dispersion relations" for electrons in a solid. That is, $\varepsilon(\vec{k})$ which tells us how the energy (the eigenvalue with respect to the Hamiltonian of the system) of a particular electron changes as the wavevector of the state varies. Even for the free electron case, after we take into account Bloch's theorem and fold all of the parts of the dispersion relation back into the first Brillouin zone, the dispersion relation looks rather complex:

What I do not understand, is how these dispersion relations generate a band structure. For example, take this figure from Kittel:

Where I have marked a particular piece of the figure in red. I do not understand what the grey boundaries in the figure mean. Somehow they mean "electrons are filling these states", but I do not understand what this means, for example, the point marked in red cannot be occupied with an electron? There is no electron with sufficient energy to have a wavevector corresponding to the point marked in red. For that matter, no electrons can exist at points except those that lie on the dispersion relation, so what gives? What do the grey areas represent?

You're right. The gray shading doesn't denote filled states, which are only located on the dispersion curves. In fact, each branch of the dispersion relation represents a single eigenstate of the Hamiltonian modified using the Bloch theorem by the substitution of $\Psi(\vec r)=\exp(i\vec k\vec r)u(\vec r),$ where $\vec k$ is a parameter and $u$ is periodic with the period of the lattice. There are no eigenstates between them.
In fact, when I was studying solid-state physics at the university, my professor specifically mentioned that some books illustrate state filling wrongly, exactly because of this mistaken shading. His own way of showing the filled states was as in the following picture. The discrete points here make more sense if we consider a finite crystal with Born—von Karman boundary conditions, because the points can then represent the discrete $\vec k$-space.


But it's a little misleading to say that the bands below the Fermi energy are "filled" (or "occupied"), because the reality is that the Fermi level is supported by a jumble of electrons in a complex many-body state that will only approximately resemble a perfect electron gas.  As electrons are depleted from the system (in bulk), the shape of the bands would change dramatically (because the bands don't represent electron states: they represent single hole-type quasi-particle excitations, i.e. perturbations from the ground state.)

@TLDR this is the same kind of approximation (self-consistent field) as the multi-electron atomic orbital model. Same there: removal of electrons one by one will also dramatically change the orbitals and their energies.

Are you absolutely sure? The self-consistent field method gives only qualitative results for ground state calculations, and becomes even less accurate for excited states (e.g. conduction states), and there's no reason to expect a priori that the orbitals and energies that come out of it (that describe low-energy core electrons as well as valence electrons) will align with the quasi-particle states.

@TLDR I see what you mean. This makes sense for atoms and other few-electron systems. But, given the amount of electrons in a crystal, I expect that exciting a single electron will only slightly alter the environment. So it would at least follow the expected single-particle band structure when it's excited higher and higher. (I've never tried to do the SCF calculations though, so I may well be wrong.)

You essentially have two questions: what's up with the grey-filled area, and how to get from the first dispersion relation to the others?
Regarding the different dispersion relations, at the moment, I can't think of a good answer other than to say it's quantum math. You can look up level repulsion and avoided crossing to get details that I think will satisfy you. Edit: See here for a condensed matter physics blog mentioning that those effects are the norm.
As for the grey-filled areas, your suspicion is correct. They are meaningless. The artist has tried to illustrate the band structure filling in a poor manner. It would have been better to, say, only draw solid lines below $\epsilon_F$ and dashed lines above it to show occupancy and lack of occupancy.

I think the actual theoretical basis for the existence of dispersion relations has less to do with avoided crossing (which is more of an AMO topic) and more to do with scaling, relevant/irrelevant operators, and the renormalization group.  Outside of toy models of perfect electron gases (and weak perturbations thereof), dispersion relations describe very specific quasi-particle excitations, not actual electrons.

@TLDR Well, I didn't wantto take the time to answer OP's question in full, but I could give him some direction for the first. I disagree that level repulsion is more of an AMO topic. If I recall correctly, it is the first-order effect that Ashcroft & Mermin use to show how the band gap opens up at the BZ boundaries in figures like OP's Figure 8. The ubiquity in CMP of the effects I mentioned are mentioned here: https://thiscondensedlife.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/avoided-crossings-level-repulsion-or-anti-crossing/

@TLDR Besides that, if we are trying to help people, I think we need to look at who is asking the question. I think your suggestions aim rather high for OP. To illustrate this, I will say I am not even sure what is meant by "scaling, relevant/irrelevant operators, and the renormalization group". I learned from Ashcroft & Mermin, and I don't recall these specific terms making an appearance.

The renormalization group explains how weakly interacting quasiparticles emerge as the long-wavelength and low-energy excitations of macroscopic condensed matter systems.  The quasiparticle dispersion relation comes out of large $N$ behavior of a crystalline solid: it might share qualitative features with certain one-/few- particle models (especially in a pseudo-potential approximation) but the actual system can exhibit singular phase transitions for which there is no finite (one or two-particle) counterpart.

For example, "level repulsion" is relevant to random matrix theory, where it explains why the spectra of random matrices seem to have almost regular spacing between adjacent levels: but in the thermodynamic (large $N$) limit, these levels still form a continuum (the Wigner semi-circle law.)

The shaded gray areas are energy states where electrons occupy those states.  For the area with the "red x" the electrons do not occupy near the top of the band (hence the white area), because they are occupying the lower part of the band to the left. The electrons occupy the band on the left because it has a lower energy relative to the top of band by the "red x."

I disagree. I believe no electron can sit at the position labeled by the red x because the wavevector and energy of that electron will not satisfy the dispersion relation. There exists no such solution to the eigenvalue problem of the Hamiltonian of the system. Hence my confusion about the shaded areas.

I think I see your confusion.  The dispersion relation you're referring to defines the boundary of the band, which in your diagrams are the dark line.  An electron is allowed to have an energy less than (or greater than) that boundary.  It can't however, have an energy within the "band gap," which is the white space between the 2 dark lines.

For clarity, if the band is concave down, then an electron can have energies less than the peak of the band.   If the band is concave up, then an electron can have an energy greater than the bottom of the band.

@JQK Your first sentence, "The shaded gray areas are energy states where electrons occupy those states", is not correct. The statement in your comment, "The dispersion relation you're referring to defines the boundary of the band..." is also incorrect. The lines are the band structure, and only these show us what allowed energy and wave vector an electron (in the independent electron approximation) may have. I don't know what you are trying to say with your concave comments.

If there is any physical significance to the grey-shaded regions, it might be more accurate to think of them as (crude) "envelopes" of (upper and lower segments) of the entire many-body spectrum of the metal, or all states that could potentially interact, directly or indirectly, with an external probe.
Admittedly, the figure isn't especially realistic: it might be more accurate to think of it as showing a narrow sector of states near the Fermi level.  Remember that the allowed energies of electrons that contribute to conduction near the ground state (i.e. at reasonable energies) are determined by the Fermi energy, which depends on the density of electrons, and is typically quite large (you would expect a value roughly proportional to the inverse square of the lattice spacing, which is already quite small.)  Hence, you would expect the electrons in crystalline solids to occupy states with high "effective wave-vector", or low-energy many-body states that "present" as such to external probes.
Dispersion relations only describe a very small part of the full (many-body) electronic structure of a solid: namely, the part that behaves like weakly-interacting quasi-particles.  When you measure dispersion relations of a solid through, e.g., scattering experiments, you are essentially "scratching the (Fermi) surface": below the Fermi energy there is a vast sea of electrons with structure over an enormous range of length scales, down to and including the lattice spacing (e.g. the core electrons near each ion.)  Interactions, disorder and impurity effects tend to "smear out" band structure and confine states, but the associated states still exist, and the ones closest to the quasiparticle modes/excitations will tend to contribute to physical processes in tangible ways.
Given the band structure for a solid, in some ways it would be misleading to say that the levels below the Fermi energy were "occupied" (and that bands above the Fermi energy are "unoccupied".) The bands specifically represent quasi-particle-like excitations of electron- or hole- type, and these excitations are essentially small perturbations from the ground state of the system.  If you peeled off electrons in bulk (e.g. $\mathcal O(10^{20})$ at a time, for a sample with $\mathcal O (N_A)$ unit cells), you would dramatically change the properties of the system, and the dispersion relation would change accordingly.  The dispersion relation can be thought of as a mean-field approximation to the physics of excitations to the electronic structure.

Band structures do live in a reciprocal space of three wave vector dimensions and one of energy, like you say. However, these plots are always along high symmetry directions and never represent a projection onto them from outside their "slice".
When you said "conduction band", I think you meant "valence band". When speaking, I make this mistake, too. I'm not a fan of your use of "ground state". If I moved a single electron from the valence band up to the conduction band, the material wouldn't be in the ground state anymore, but the Fermi energy would not change.

Did I say "conduction band"?

No, I guess you said "conducting bands".

Would it be fair to say that if a band intersects the Fermi level, it contributes to conduction?

Sorry for the brevity in my last comment. I originally misread you. You didn't say "conduction bands. I think "conducting bands" is fine. If we could edit comments, I would strike-through that part of my original comment.

@Dr.Nate Admittedly I edited my original answer, in which (with the aid of Ctrl F) I was able to confirm the offending phrase did occur.  I also removed the potentially misleading discussion of projections of bands over two and three dimensions.
